# On click aria-expanded="false" not change and 'show' class also not addes in bootstrap dropdown Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using the bootstrap dropdown in my Angular project. but on click is not showing dropdown-menu. actually, after clicking, the show class not added in the drop-down and aria-expanded="false" is not change into "true

```
<div class="dropdown>
 <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle f-f-r f-14" type="button" id="dropdown123" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Save Button
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu f-f-r f-14 p-t-12 p-b-12" aria-labelledby="dropdown123">
  <a class="dropdown-item"

    <button>S1 </button>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item">
    <button>S2 </button>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item">
    <button>S3 </button>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code please, how do we know the problem without code?

Comment: Put your related snippet of code

Comment: check it now @fatemefazli

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I hope this will help.

Comment: I got the solution. my dropdown is not working because of stop Propagation. I used stopPropagation() in parent component that's y its stop working.  @fatemefazli

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code without your custom style classes and only added a missing `"` at `<div class="dropdown">` and a missing `>` at `< class="dropdown-item">` and it worked for me.

Here is the working code with the missing stuff and without your custom css.

```
    <div class="dropdown">
 <button class=" btn btn-secondary
        dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown123"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Save Button <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="dropdown123">
            <a class="dropdown-item">
                <button>S1</button>
            </a> <a class="dropdown-item">
                <button>S2</button>
            </a> <a class="dropdown-item">
                <button>S3</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If it does not work please check if you are using Bootstrap 4, maybe it was different with V3 but I dont think so, not sure though.